# How to call an object created in a module

Tags: python, class, object, module

I have a problem with class in Python.
I'd like to know how to call an object created in a module in other python program.

Let me show an example. I have these object in "class_module.py" file

```
def objectCase():
    object1 = class_name("object1")
    object2 = class_name("object2")
    object3 = class_name("object3")

def other_objectCase():
    other_object1 = class_name("other_object1")
    other_object2 = class_name("other_object2")
    other_object3 = class_name("other_object3")
```

With `from class_module.py import *`, I think if I use the `objectCase()` function, I have in my program these object `(object1, object2, object3)` and, if I use `otherobjectCase()` function, I call all `otherobject`.
But this is not true.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating local variables inside the functions.  They are lost as soon as the function returns.  If you need these objects later on, `return` them to the caller

```
return object1, object2, object3
```

and bind names to them in the calling code

```
a, b, c = objectCase()
```

Comment: How Can I keep the same name present in function (so "object1", "object2" instead "a", "b") automatically?

Comment: @SniperWolf: Essentially, no.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at to documentation for [Scopes and Namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), the names `object1`, `object2`, and `object3` are local to the `objectCase()` function, so you will not be able to access them from your main module as your code is currently written.

The most typical way of accomplishing what you want would be to return those variables:

```
def objectCase():
    object1 = class_name("object1")
    object2 = class_name("object2")
    object3 = class_name("object3")
    return object1, object2, object3
```

And then when you call it assign the returned values back to the same names:

```
object1, object2, object3 = objectCase()
```

There isn't a good way to keep the same names as the local variables automatically, but returning a dictionary may be appropriate here.  Instead of returning `object1, object2, object3` you could return `{'object1': object1, 'object2': object2, 'object3': object3}`, and then the calling function could do something like this:

```
result = objectCase()
# do something with result['object1'], result['object2'], or result['object3']
```

Comment: I have the same question reading this answer. How Can I keep the same name present in function (so "object1", "object2" instead "a", "b") automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `object1`, ... to be in the module's namespace you have several options:

```
object1, object2, object3 = objectCase()
```

or, if you don't want to deal with the assignments there, you can use the `global` keyword in the function:

```
def objectCase():
    global object1, object2, object3
    object1 = class_name("object1")
    object2 = class_name("object2")
    object3 = class_name("object3")
```

or, you can skip the function altogether and just have this as top-level code:

```
object1 = class_name("object1")
object2 = class_name("object2")
object3 = class_name("object3")
```

Comment: `global` will actually not work here, because this function is being imported from another module and global variables are global to the module, not across modules.

Comment: `global` will make the objects global in module they are created in, then `from module import *` will be able to pick them up.

Comment: True, but doing `from module import *` every time you call a function from `module` that updates global variables would be a pretty messy program structure.

Comment: @F.J, using `global` is messy ;) .  On re-reading his question, I think you and Sven have the correct interpretation of what he was asking -- I was thinking he wanted his objects in the module he defined the functions in.